# Making is_reference work inside a function template for reference without knowing the type on which the function is to be instantiated

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits, c++03

Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
template<typename T>
class IsReference {
   private:
     typedef char One;
     typedef struct { char a[2]; } Two;
     template<typename C> static One test(C*);
     template<typename C> static Two test(...);
   public:
     enum { val = sizeof(IsReference<T>::test<T>(0)) == 1 };
     enum {result = !val};

};

template < class T>
void foo(T t){
  std::cout<< IsReference<T>::result << "\n";
}

class C{
  public: int a;
};

int main(){
  C c1;
  C &c2 = c1;
  foo(c1);
  foo(c2);
}
```

The output is `0` for `foo(c2)` also which I don't want.

Inside `foo` how can I check whether `T` is reference type or not?
I dont want to call `foo` as `foo<C&>(c2)` i.e we don't know on which type the function is getting instantiated.

Comment: I dont understand what this means

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb : Which part was difficult to understand?

Comment: You are trying to reimplement boost::is_reference from Boost.TypeTraits, right?

Comment: Wouldn't partial specialization be enough to implement `IsReference`?

Comment: @LucTouraille Yes, it's a lot easier and you don't even need to take care of rvalue references in C++03. I don't see what OP is trying here.

Comment: (1) IsReference is way more complicated than it has to be. Simple partial specialization would be fine. (2) You're under the impression that the "reference-ness" of a reference in an expression remains part of the type. But it does not. The use of a reference as expression makes the compiler adjust the type to be a non-reference type and then everything else follows. Also, T will NEVER be deduced to be a reference. Check the chapter on template argument deduction in your favorite C++ book. To put it simply: References are special.

Comment: @LucTouraille : Yes that would be enough but that's not what I am asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. As an expression, `c2` is an lvalue of type `C`, just like `c1`, so in both cases argument-dependent lookup will choose `foo<C>`.

You get [the same result](http://ideone.com/tlvAB) using Boost.TypeTraits.

There may be some new wizardry in C++11 to help, but (a) I don't know enough about C++11 to answer, and (b) you've tagged the question C++03 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**For edited question**:

> I dont want to call foo as `foo<C&>(c2)` i.e we don't know on which type
>   the function is getting instantiated

It's **not possible**. Because, when an object or reference are passed to a function, the function is not aware whether it's an object or reference.

Here is one proposed C++11 solution (using macro);

```
#define FOO(X) foo<decltype(X)>(X)
```

Use `FOO` instead of `foo`

Comment: Yes. I understand why its working like that. The title is misleading.

Comment: @PrasoonSaurav, check the updated answer. I don't know who has downvoted

Comment: Now the question remains 'how to simulate decltype in C++03?' :P

Comment: @PrasoonSaurav, not **entirely** possible (especially this case where you have to use *object* to find a type). That's why it's introduced in C++11. :)

Answer (score -1):

I think it should be

```
template<typename C> static One test(C&);
```

rather than `One test(C*)`